# How to solve sql problem on matching unrequited?

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I am a beginner in sql and I have the following problems that I want to know how to solve.

Below is a list with CA CB, so if value in CA CB appears in CB CA returns true, otherwise returns false.

```
CA CB
6  5 
5  6 
2  3 
3  2 
4  1
```

Results should be like this

```
CA CB  
6  5  True
5  6  True 
2  3  True 
3  2  True 
4  1  False
```

If anyone know how I could write a sql to express it?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: See LEFT JOIN. At this point, 5 minutes in the company of any basic, introductory book or tutorial would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a self-join of the same table with different alias names

```
select t1.ca, t1.cb, 
       case when t2.ca is not null 
            then 'true' 
            else 'false' 
       end as result
from your_table t1
left join your_table t2 on t1.cb = t2.ca
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `exists`:

```
select t.*,
       (exists (select 1
                from t t2
                where t2.ca = t.cb and t2.cb = t.ca
               )
       ) as flag
from t;
```

Here are some reasons I recommend this approach.

First, `exists` is insensitive to duplicates.  You don't specify if a given pair can appear more than once.  But if they can, then a `left join` can multiply rows.

Second, a `case` expression is not needed.  MySQL supports booleans, so you can just use boolean expressions.

Third, the performance should be very similar between the two approaches (assuming no duplicates; with duplicates this may be faster).  Both `exists` and `left join` can use an index on `(ca, cb)`.

EDIT:

If you wanted to filter for the unmatched pairs, you would use `not exists` in the `where` clause:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.ca = t.cb and t2.cb = t.ca
                 );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! How about if I just want to show the last 4,1 pair? how would the SQL be differently?

Comment: @Tinky . . . That is not the question you asked here, but it just requires moving the logic to the `where` clause.

Comment: Congratulations @GordonLinoff on getting 1M Reputation `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

Well just for contribution, you could do this as well:

```
select *,
case when CA in (select distinct CB from YOUR_TABLE) or
          CB in (select distinct CA from YOUR_TABLE)
     then 'False'
     else 'True'
end as check_1
from YOUR_TABLE
```

I saw your question about how to show the `True` row only so:

```
with cts as 
(
case when CA in (select distinct CB from YOUR_TABLE) or
          CB in (select distinct CA from YOUR_TABLE)
     then 'False'
     else 'True'
end as check_1
from YOUR_TABLE
)
select * from cts where check_1 = 'True'
```